# MySql Constraint to have particular fields value greater than zero

Tags: mysql, check-constraints

I have the following MySql syntax to create a table with constraint to check P_Id column have value greater than zero, but it still allows me to add values less than 0 like -1,-2, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons(
    P_Id int NOT NULL ,
    LastName varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
    FirstName varchar( 255 ) ,
    Address varchar( 255 ) ,
    City varchar( 255 ) ,
    CHECK (
        P_Id >0
    )
)
```

Is there anything that i am doing  wrong in above structure to have value for P_Id > 0 ??

Comment: Is P_Id supposed to be a primary key? If so, you're better off letting MySQL handle it using `PRIMARY KEY  (`P_Id`)` with `AUTO_INCREMENT` as an option on P_Id.

Comment: no, P_Id is not supposed to be a Primary key.

Comment: would UNSIGNED INT work for you?

Comment: yes, UNSIGNED INT worked, but i want to make use of Constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check constraints don't work in mysql. You have to make some trick to emulate them.
Take a look at this article

http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints

Comment: The link seems dead now.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a derived

```
tinyint NOT NULL
```

column called

```
id_check
```

with (for example) the formula

```
(IF(id<1,NULL,1))
```

(many other variants feasible)

Be aware that column names are non-case-sensitive, so best lowercase them.

Comment: I now prefer it like this: `\`CHECK_id\` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AS (IF(id>0,1,-1))`, because that leads to a clearer error message.